# How can I get last item of Flux without collapsing it with reduce() or last()

Tags: java, project-reactor, reactive-streams

How can I get last item of Flux without collapsing it with reduce() or last() ? Here is my use-case:

1) I have generator that produces `Flux<T>` based on state.
2) When inner `Flux` completes it alters the state that affect next `Flux` objects I emit in generator.

Schematicaly it looks like this

```
static class State {
    int secret = 2;
    int iteration = 0;
}

Random rand = new Random(1024);
Flux<Integer> stream = Flux.<Flux<Integer>, State>generate(State::new, (state, sink) -> {

    System.out.println(String.format("Generate: %d", state.secret));
    Flux<Integer> inner = Flux.range(1, rand.nextInt(10));

    sink.next(inner.doOnComplete(() -> {
        // How do I get last item of `inner` here ?
        // For example I'd like to decrement `state.secret` by last value of `inner`
    }));

    return state;
}).flatMap(Function.identity());
```

UPD: I unmarked my answer because the hack turned out to be unreliable. It's possible that `.generate()` will be invoked before previous `Flux` is fully consumed therefore making value in `last` incorrect.

Comment: Can you call `share()` on your inner flux to allow multiple subscribers, which would enable you to call `last()` without an issue?

Comment: @MichaelBerry Wouldn't it increase risk of missing items at the beginning of the stream because source is now hot ?

Comment: Potentially, yes. If you can feasibly `cache()` the entire thing then it doesn't matter so much however, but if not (and missing elements matter) then it's not an approach I'd recommend.

Comment: As I do not have a something to test it out right now. Would you like to try the materialize of the stream? as it will convert it to signals + context It may have the last value in "complete" signal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First version was unreliable. I hacked another one:

```
static <T> Flux<T> expandOnLastItem(Supplier<Flux<T>> seed, Function<T, Flux<T>> generator) {
    return Flux.just(new AtomicReference<T>())
            .flatMap(last -> Flux.just(seed.get().materialize())
                    .flatMap(Function.identity())
                    .expand(v -> {
                        if (v.hasValue()) {
                            last.set(v.get());
                        } else if (v.isOnComplete() && last.get() != null) {
                            Flux<T> res = generator.apply(last.get());
                            last.set(null);
                            return res.materialize();
                        }
                        return Flux.empty();
                    })
                    .filter(s -> !s.isOnComplete())
                    .dematerialize());
}
```

which can be used as

```
static Flux<Integer> getPage(int pageId, int size) {
    return Flux.defer(() -> {
        if (pageId < 3) {
            System.out.println("Returning data for pageId: " + pageId);
            return Flux.range(pageId * 100, size);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Returning empty for pageId: " + pageId);
            return Flux.empty();
        }
    });
}

expandOnLastItem(
        () -> getPage(0, 5),
        lastId -> {
            System.out.println("  Expanding. Last item: " + lastId);
            int curPage = lastId / 100;
            return getPage(curPage + 1, 5);
        })
        .reduce(0L, (count, value) -> {
            System.out.println("==> " + value);
            return count + 1;
        })
        .block();
```

---

So I hacked it by mutating state variable in generator. It works but it's not very functional. If anyone else can suggest alternative I'll greatly appreciate it.

```
Random rand = new Random(1024);
Flux.<Flux<String>, State>generate(State::new, (state, sink) -> {

    if (state.iteration < 4) {
        final int count = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
        System.out.println(String.format("*** Generate %d: start %d (count %d)", state.iteration, state.secret, count));
        Flux<Integer> inner = Flux.range(state.secret, count);

        final int[] last = {Integer.MIN_VALUE};
        sink.next(
                inner
                        .doOnNext(value -> {
                            last[0] = value;
                        })
                        .map(value -> String.format("Iter %d value %d", state.iteration, value))
                        .doOnComplete(() -> {
                            System.out.println(String.format("Inner complete (last item was %d)", last[0]));
                            state.secret = last[0];
                            state.iteration += 1;
                        }));
    } else {
        System.out.println("Generate complete");
        sink.complete();
    }

    return state;
})
        .flatMap(Function.identity())
        .map(value -> {
            System.out.println(String.format("Ext map: %s", value));
            return value;
        })
        .buffer(5)
        .flatMapIterable(Function.identity())
        .subscribe(value -> System.out.println(String.format("  ---> %s", value)));

System.out.println("Exiting");
```

Comment: A mutating variable was the only "quick" way I thought of, but I didn't want to answer with that as it's... hacky, as you demonstrate! At the very least I'd use an `AtomicInteger` here rather than a raw array. You might be able to make it a bit nicer by wrapping the "hacky" stuff inside a separate processor that tracks the last emitted value, but it'd still be doing essentially the same thing. If I think of a better solution I'll post it.

Comment: @MichaelBerry Can you think of scenario when it breaks? E.g. is it possible that downstream requests more items than available in inner stream, thus triggering new call of generate before 1st inner stream is complete (and causing `last[0]` to have not the last element) ?